# Расшифровка кода, общий смысл которого понятен

Tags: c++builder, ms-word, byte

Нужна помощь с расшифровкой кода, общий смысл понятен, но есть некоторые нюансы.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        BYTE buf[20];

        BYTE aa;
        WORD bb; // WORD(тип принадлежащей Pascal'ю)тоже самое что и unsigned short int
        unsigned long cc;

        *(buf)=23;  // 1)
        *(buf+10)=23;
        aa=*(buf);

        *((WORD *)buf)=0x1234;  // 2)
        bb=*((WORD *)buf);  // 3)

        *((unsigned long *)buf)=0x12345678;
        cc=*((unsigned long *)buf);

        //  4)
        /*  
        (WORD *)buf[0]=0x1234;
        bb=(WORD *)buf[0];
        */

        getch();
        return 0;
}
```

**1)** непонятная запись, то-есть операция разыменования buf и присвоения ему числа - выглядит это так. Но по отладке заметно присвоение 1-му элементу buf числа.

**2)** (WORD *) - это как понять, приведение типа byte и к типу word и инициализация его? Или же указывает на то, что 1-му и 2-му элементу buf`а присвоит значения(0х34 и 0х12).

**3)** присвоит bb - 1-ий и 2-ий элемент buf как одно целое?

**4)** Можно ли делать все те же операции но помощью индексов? У меня не вышло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этих случаях buf является указателем на область памяти, в которой хранятся элементы массива. Отсюда и все наблюдаемые феномены.

```
*((WORD *)buf)=0x1234;
```

Получаем указатель на начало массива, преобразуем его в указатель на тип short (через (WORD*)buf). И потом через разыменование пишем в этот short, адрес которого совпадает с адресом начала массива, значение. В итоге первые два элемента массива будут записаны. Третий пункт - ровно наоборот, получить short с адреса начала массива.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь всё ясно.